# How to load PhantomJS in Gradle automatically

Tags: gradle, phantomjs, gradle-plugin

How can I configure my Gradle script to automatically download PhantomJS for my tests to use, so that I don't have to manually install it somewhere on my build server?

I see a [phantomjs-maven-plugin](https://github.com/klieber/phantomjs-maven-plugin) that seems to do exactly what I want, but I don't know how to use it in Gradle.